# Eigen and ctest failing on i386 with GCC 7

Tags: gcc, fedora, eigen3

I'm trying to build PHD2 on Fedora, but I get ctests failing using GCC7 only on i386 architecture. With GCC7 on x86_64 ctests are passing, the same for i386 and x86_64 with GCC6.

This is the [report](https://github.com/OpenPHDGuiding/phd2/issues/608) on PHD2 github.

Can be a Eigen3 problem only on i386 when using GCC7?

Comment: a) I'm not hugely sure what the question is - this looks more like a misplaced bug report. b) https://github.com/OpenPHDGuiding/phd2/blob/9c4a18dfc2a1f3c35c1746e1eaeb450bd80627a8/contributions/MPI_IS_gaussian_process/tests/gaussian_process/math_tools_test.cpp#L163 - if you wanted to investigate it yourself you could print the values to see what it's generating vs what it should be.

Comment: c) It could potentially be either a compiler bug, or an Eigen/PHD2 bug. The latter is probably more likely - there's lots of opportunities for undefined behaviour in C++. Code that relies on (say) uninitialized memory being set to 0 could easily end up with this kind of bug.

Comment: (ignore point b - it looks like it's in the bug report...)

Comment: Does the eigen test-suite pass on i386 with GCC 7 (or with any other compiler you have access to)? If it does not, file a bug report for that on http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/bz/). If the test-suite passes, try reducing your failing unit-tests to self-containing examples (i.e., not relying on 3rd party libraries) and file (a) bug report(s) for those issues.